# StackoverflowException when using Unity IOC

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am using unity in a Winforms app by injecting the dependency into the constructor of the form (I know this is not best practice) but it does work but I am getting a stackoverflowexception when I am trying to load the mdi form.

is there any way to trace what unity is trying to resolve and somehow find out what is happening?

I have a working example that I know works using this 'design'.

I know this is not an ideal design and I plan on introducing a Presenter down the line but for now this should work and I don't know why it is not

EDIT: 
I know I have services that reference each other for example

```
public class Service1(IService2, IService3, IService4):IService1

public class Service2(IService1, IService5):IService2
```

will this cause an exception?

EDIT2: yes I just created an quick app with this circular reference as listed in my first edit and I got a StackOverflowException - obviously not allowed.

Comment: "into the constructor of the form". This actually is the best practice. Ctor injection works fine in win forms and is ctor injection is best practice when it comes to dependency injection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you catch the exception in VS go inside it and follow `InnerException`. Unity should print all registered types and you can see which is missing.

Also look at stack trace. Usually `StackOverflow` appears when you have circular dependecies like this:

```
class A { A(B b) { ... } }
class B { B(A a) { ... } }
```

`A` depends on `B` and vice versa. Unity will try to inject in `ctor` of `A` a `B` instance but a `B` instance needs an `A` instance which, again, needs a `B` and so on.

This example is a trivial one but in real work the circularity is harder to spot as there might be a more complex graph of dependencies, between different libraries, like `A` -> `B` -> `C` -> `D` -> `A` (where "->" means "depends on").

**EDIT**
Yes, that cross-references services can lead you to a stackoverflow exception if at the moment you're resolving `IService1`, `IService1` itself is not registered yet;

**Solution 1** 
You can bypass this problem if types registration and resolving happens in two steps (rough idea):

1. Registration register both `IService1` and its type and `IService2` and its type. This step is doing only registration code and do not process any other things (UI, startup logic, unity resolving, http comms, etc).
2. Actual application logic starts; now you can resolve anything.

**Solution 2**

Use empty `ctors` and doing the resolve inside `Service` class. You can use `RegisterType` method to specify that the empty `ctor` must be called:

```
container.RegisterType<IServiceProvider, ServiceContainer>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

Here are more details about [circular references with dependency injection using Unity.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660897(v=pandp.20).aspx)

**Solution 3**

Use `Lazy<IService>` for resolving. Using this the actual resolving will happen on demand, more specific when the first time `Lazy.Value` property is called first time.

Comment: see my edit..is that what you mean for inthat case I will then have circular refs

Comment: Edited with more comments and some possible solutions.

Comment: The URL to more info in  solution2  is empty

Comment: @kurasa you're right, I edited the link again and it works now.